# How to find an image at any lighting conditions using OpenCV template Matching?

Tags: python, opencv, templates, matching

I am using the OpenCV Template Matching method for detecting the icons on a screen captured by a Raspberry Pi camera.

But here the problem is, whenever there is a change in the lighting conditions of the captured screen, the template matching method will not able to identify icons on the screen.

Note: I am using a threshold value of 0.8. If we decrease the threshold value, it gives a false match.

So is there any solution to get rid both errors? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some code or examples to get a better understanding of your problem?

Comment: Post your images to some free hosting service and put the URLs here so we can see what kind of images and what lighting changes you have. One suggestion is to convert the images to edges and then match the edges with the template matching.

Answer (score 1):

What you likely want is to run the template matching with the zero mean normalized cross correlation (ZNCC) method. From the [Wikipedia section on ZNCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Zero-normalized_cross-correlation_(ZNCC)):

> For image-processing applications in which the brightness of the image and template can vary due to lighting and exposure conditions, the images can be first normalized. This is typically done at every step by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation.

OpenCV implements this in `matchTemplate()` with the `TM_CCOEFF_NORMED` mode, as shown in the docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695d).

For an example of this working, let's create a blank image, and a random template, and we'll place the template into the image, only with half the brightness:

```py
img = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
tmp = np.uint8(255*np.random.rand(10, 10))
img[45:55, 45:55] = 0.5 * tmp
```

Now, using the ZNCC method, we still see that the max ZNCC value in the response corresponds to the template location:

```py
resp = cv.matchTemplate(img, tmp, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
minval, maxval, minloc, maxloc = cv.minMaxLoc(resp)
print(maxloc)  # (45, 45)
```